# Are [syslog] or [rsyslog] programming related?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I've spent quite some time *trying* to clean up questions on both [syslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syslog) and [rsyslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsyslog).

Syslog is a protocol for message logging and can be used to send event logs to a server. Often I'm unsure, if I should answer a question, flag it for closure as *off-topic* or just redirect the user to, e.g., [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour) or [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

I've received comments which stated that I shouldn't have answered a question and just flagged it, but I've also recently received a warning that some flags have been declined.

Maybe my judgement is just so bad that I don't know when to answer vs. when to flag a question, which has just led me to stop answering and flagging questions altogether.

Are [syslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syslog) and [rsyslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsyslog) programming related? Is the line between "programming" (scripting a configuration?) and "not programming" (not scripting?) that thin?

Comment: *Writing* or *reading* from syslog in a programmatic way would be programming related, no? We've got quite questions on logging to files etc, syslog just seems like another backend.

Comment: I wouldn't both VTC and also answer a question: if you think it should be closed then you think nobody should answer it on this site.  "How do I set up syslogd" is not a programming question, even if it involves plain-text files and the same editors a programmer might use, and I might leave a comment suggesting it go on `[unix.se]` or `[devops.se]`.

Comment: [tag:asterisk] is in a similar situation. Some of its configuration can be considered programming, and of course questions about working with the code or interfacing with APIs are fine, but probably 90% of the existing questions are off-topic. If you want to get into site curation, prepare to be frustrated!

Comment: @DavidMaze pretty sure they're not talking about flagging and answering the *same* questions. I edited to make that more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about how to programmatically log to syslog or how to programmatically receive syslog messages are programming-related and on-topic.

Questions about installation, maintenance, etc. of a syslog daemon or syslog server, performance requirements, hardware recommendations, operating system recommendations, firewall rules, etc. for a syslog server are not programming-related and thus off-topic.

Questions about configuration are … tricky. I would argue that at least Rsyslog's [*advanced* configuration file format (previously known as RainerScript)](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/#rainerscript) is complex enough (it has [expressions](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/expressions.html#expressions), [functions](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/functions/#functions), [conditionals](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/control_structures.html#if-else-if-else), [loops](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/control_structures.html#foreach), and [subroutine calls](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/rainerscript_call.html#the-rsyslog-call-statement)) to be reasonably classified as a programming language, and Rsyslog configuration using the advanced format to be reasonably classified as programming.

However, the fact that it is *technically* programming and *technically* on-topic on Stack Overflow does not mean that SO is the best place for it. I would guess that the number of Rsyslog configuration experts on SO is much lower than, say, on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (but please note that Rsyslog also has a [Windows Agent](https://www.rsyslog.com/windows-agent/) that can forward Windows Event Logs to Rsyslog), or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) (but only if the question actually is within a DevOps context and about a DevOps problem). But the fact that you will get better answers somewhere else doesn't make a question off-topic, it just makes it a sub-optmimal choice of site.

A sub-optimal choice of site only warrants a comment informing the asker about the superior options, not more.

Note that the Rsyslog documentation [*explicitly* advertises ServerFault](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/#configuration) and not Stack Overflow:

> See also
>
> Help with configuring/using `Rsyslog`:
>
> - [Mailing list](http://lists.adiscon.net/mailman/listinfo/rsyslog) – best route for general questions
> - GitHub: [rsyslog source project](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/) – detailed questions, reporting issues that are believed to be bugs with `Rsyslog`
> - Stack Exchange ([View](https://stackexchange.com/filters/327462/rsyslog), [Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask?tags=rsyslog)) – experimental support from rsyslog community

Where the *View* link goes to a global network-wide filter and the *Ask* link specifically directs to the *Ask Question* form on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

[I can write my Java logs to Syslog through Log4J2.](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/SyslogAppender.html)  I have done this before in my professional career, and I have had to modify code to do it.

Syslog questions are on-topic for programmers.

Comment: Absolutely *some* syslog question are on-topic, like the example you give. But the fact that some questions are on topic doesn't mean they all are. See, for example, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74098725/selective-logs-via-rsyslog), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141882/yocto-syslog-will-not-create-folder), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971174/how-to-make-containerd-forward-logs-to-journald)